# Problema al importar un modulo de un paquete distribuible

Tags: python

Tengo un problema al importar el modulo `classclient`. Ya cree el paquete redistribuible y lo instale. Incluso hago `pip list` y en la lista aparece classclient para poder importarlo. Sin embargo, cuando trato de importarlo me salta el siguiente error:

```
>>> import classclient
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'classclient'
```

Esto es lo que me aparece cuando hago `pip list`

```
Package         Version
--------------- --------
asgiref         3.6.0
classclient     1.0.0
Django          4.1.7
numpy           1.24.2
pandas          1.5.3
pip             23.0.1
python-dateutil 2.8.2
pytz            2022.7.1
setuptools      65.5.0
six             1.16.0
sqlparse        0.4.3
tzdata          2022.7
```

Comment: Depende de qué clase este implementada en el paquete. Es posible que debas usar algo como `import algunaClase from classclient`...

Comment: Es posible (aunque no muy corriente) que el nombre con que se instala el paquete (y que sale con `pip list`) no sea el mismo que haya que poner en el import. Por ejemplo eso hace el paquete BeautifulSoup que se instala con `pip install beautifulsoup4` pero luego se importa con `import bs4`. Quizás has hecho algo así con tu paquete (probablemente por error). Veo que tu paquete no está en pipy ¿es público?

Comment: abulafia Puede ser que por error haya implementado alguna abreviatura de las que comentas. Hay alguna forma de averiguarla?
El paquete no es publico.

Comment: Dentro de setup.py declaras el nombre del paquete. Ese es el nombre con que es "publicado" (el que usará pip). Por otro lado, la implementación estará en una carpeta "al lado" de setup.py. Es el nombre de esa carpeta el que debes usar en import. Normalmente debería coincidir con el declarado en el setup, pero sospecho que no es así en tu caso.

Comment: Ya pude resolverlo. El error era que no estaba colocando en el atributo `name` del setup.py, el mismo nombre que el paquete que intentaba distribuir.